# Newlines in sed on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, bash, regex, sed

I find that `\n` doesn't work in sed under Mac OS X.
Specifically, say I want to break the words separated by a single space into lines:

```
# input
foo bar
```

I use,

```
echo "foo bar" | sed 's/ /\n/'
```

But the result is stupid, the `\n` is not escaped!

```
foonbar
```

After I consulted to google, I found a [workaround](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/#comment-200):

```
echo 'foo bar' | sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'
```

After reading the article, I still cannot understand what `\'$'\n/g'` means.
Can some one explain it to me, or if there is any other way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: this would probably work too: `echo "foo bar" | tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But currently I just use the above case as an example, I do need to know how to escape a `\n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621722/removing-carriage-return-on-mac-os-x-using-sed

Comment: Maybe you could also use Perl instead of sed which would make it simpler. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777484/111036) for details. Basically, it would be `echo "foo bar" | perl -pe 's/ /\n/` or `perl -pe 's/ +/\n/g` to replace all spaces or groups of spaces by a new line.

Comment: I just noticed a script running on Big Sur escaped the newline just fine, but the same script on Catalina showed your output... not a newline.  I think Apple updated it to address this issue.

Answer (score 38):

You can `brew install gnu-sed` and replace calls to `sed` with `gsed`.

---

To use it as `sed` instead of `gsed`, brew helpfully prints the following instructions after you install:

```
GNU "sed" has been installed as "gsed".
If you need to use it as "sed", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

That is, append the following line to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Using the same software on all platform is way easier (at last to me) than dealing with every specificities of the Mac version. Beware, the option is now `--with-default-names` and *not* `--default-names`. However, this option did not worked on my installation, so I had to put a `alias gsed=sed` in my `~/.profile` to make it work.

Comment: This is an ugly workaround. It doesn't explain why `sed` on OS X behaves the way it does and makes the incorrect assumption that `gnu-sed` is more correct. Don't be a GNU-addict and stick to POSIX standards to avoid problems in the long run.

Comment: It is how Apple should make its OS works by default. Why use the name of a program and then make it works differently?  
I waste an hour because of this...

Comment: @rascio - because OS X is BSD-like and Linux is Linux-like.

Comment: @rascio I think you'll find that GNU sed is the newcomer; BSD sed dates back to 1979 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix).

Comment: This is the preferred answer in most cases I think. If you get a compile script in your lap you don't want to spend time modifying it just to make it work with OSX. Instead, simply do `brew install gnu-sed`, `alias sed='gsed'`, `sh compile.sh`, and remove the alias when you're done (`unalias sed`).

Comment: Correction: For the alias to work correctly inside the script, the command should be `source compile.sh`

Comment: `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names` gives me `Error: invalid option: --with-default-names`

Answer (score 33):

These would also work:

```
echo 'foo bar' | sed 's/ /\
/g'
```

`echo 'foo bar' | sed $'s/ /\\\n/g'`

`lf=$'\n'; echo 'foo bar' | sed "s/ /\\$lf/g"`

OS X's sed doesn't interpret `\n` in the replace pattern, but you can use a literal linefeed preceded by a line continuation character. The shell replaces `$'\n'` with a literal linefeed before the sed command is run.

Comment: Why does `sed $'s/ /\\\n/g'` work, but not `sed $'s/\\\n/ /g'`?

Comment: @alec You can't use `sed` even in linux/unix to remove newlines because its parsed/split at each newline. If you run this in linux/unix, it won't do anything either: `echo -e 'foo\nbar' | sed 's/\n//'`

Answer (score 13):

The workaround you found passes a single argument string to `sed -e`.

That argument ends up being a string in the familiar sed `s/ / /g` format.

That string is created in two parts, one after the other.

The first part is quoted in `'...'` form.

The second part is quoted in `$'...'` form.

The `'s/ /\'` part gets the single-quotes stripped off, but otherwise passes through to sed just as it looks on the command-line. That is, the backslash isn't eaten by bash, it's passed to sed.

The `$'\n/g'` part gets the dollar sign and the single-quotes stripped off, and the `\n` gets converted to a newline character.

All together, the argument becomes

s/ /\<kbd>newline</kbd>/g

[That was fun. Took a while to unwrap that. +1 for an interesting question.]

Answer (score 8):

The expression `$'...'` is a `bash`-ism which produces `...` with the standard escape sequences expanded.  Th `\'` before it just means a backslash followed by the end of the quoted section, the resulting string is `s/ /\`.  (Yes, you can switch quoting in the middle of a string; it doesn't end the string.)

POSIX standard `sed` only accepts `\n` as part of a search pattern.  OS X uses the FreeBSD `sed`, which is strictly POSIX compliant; GNU, as usual, adds extra stuff and then Linux users all think *that* is some kind of "standard" (maybe I'd be more impressed if either of them had a standards process).

Comment: Now I understand the `$'...'` part. But... what is `s/ /\ `? What do you mean by `switch quoting`?

Comment: `'...'` is one kind of shell quoting; `$'...'` is another. There's also `"..."` and `\x` to quote a single character. You can combine those in a single word, which is what was being done there, switching from a normal `''` string to a `$''` string to translate the `\n`. As for the rest, it's building up a `sed` command (`s/text/replacement/flags`). In this case the command is started, including a backslash at the end to protect the literal newline that the `$'\n/g'` appends. The result is to replace all (the `/g` flag) spaces with newlines.

Answer (score 7):

There's a very easy to visually see what's happening. Simply echo the string!

```
echo 's/$/\'$'\n/g'
```

results in

```
s/$/\
/g
```

which is equivalent to `s/$/\`<kbd>newline</kbd>`/g`

If you didn't have the extra `\` before the `newline`, the shell would interpret the `newline` as the end of the command prematurely.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

This workaround works on Mac and the script can be executed also on Linux

```
NL="\n"
if [[ $uname -eq "Darwin" ]]; then
    NL=$'\\\n'
fi

echo 'foo bar' | sed -e "s| |${NL}|"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more compact form of [@max-zerbini's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1531737/20568):

```
[[ $(uname) -eq "Darwin" ]] && NL=$'\\\n' || NL="\n"
echo 'foo bar' | sed -e "s| |${NL}|"
```