# Use OS X's sed in a script to find a string and append a line beneath it including a newline character

Tags: macos, sed

I've learned that the BSD version of sed included with OS X doesn't provide an intuitive way to add newlines.  I've found a few notes about it, but I don't understand yet, how to extend the examples to solve my problem.

I need to append several lines to a file and found that the lines I add do not include newline characters.

My shell script currently contains the following:

```
sed '/match string/  a\
newline string' ./inputfile > ./outputfile
```

And, I'm trying to apply the tip I found here [Newlines in sed on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/307165/newlines-in-sed-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind.  While reformatting the code portion of this question, a solution became clear:

I found that the following does exactly what I need:

```
sed '/match string/  a\
newline string \
' ./inputfile > ./outputfile
```

Comment: To do that on a single line, you can use ANSI-C quoting to unescape `\n`. Additional backslashes are required before the newlines. `echo $'111\n333' | sed $'/111/a\\\n222\\\n'`.