# Mac: Run screen command from launchctl

Tags: mac, shell, python, plist, launchctl

I have a Python script that I would like to run on a Mac at system start up in a detached screen session.

**The Python File (`foo.py`):**

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    print 'hello', datetime.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(2)
```

**The Shell Script Which Calls It (`run_foo.sh`):**

```
#!/bin/bash
username=`whoami`
_python=`which python`
screen -dm -S run_foo $_python /Users/$username/foo.py
```

**The Plist Which Calls The Shell Script:**
https://gist.github.com/cooncesean/6617008

===========

The Python script runs fine on its own:

```
> python foo.py
hello 2013-09-18 21:20:22.132170
hello 2013-09-18 21:20:24.133420
hello 2013-09-18 21:20:26.134697
...
```

The Shell script that calls the Python script runs fine on its own:

```
> sh run_foo.sh
There is a screen on:
1922.run_foo    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/folders/4z/0413fcs523l8nz12xbvng0bh0000gn/T/.screen.

> screen -r run_foo
hello 2013-09-18 21:24:57.243103
hello 2013-09-18 21:24:59.244349
```

Loading the plist (which calls the shell script, which creates the screen and runs the Python script) leaves me with a dead screen session that needs to be wiped.

```
> launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/start-foo.plist

> screen -list
There is a screen on:
1951.run_foo    (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
1 Socket in /var/folders/4z/0413fcs523l8nz12xbvng0bh0000gn/T/.screen.
```

**UPDATE:** It [appears launchd does not allow you to call a daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) (in this case, `screen`) and raises an exception. So, how does one start a screen session at startup on a Mac? crontab?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by piecing together a few different answers [1][2][3].

I made a script to launch my screen command as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
screen -dmS MySessionName $SHELL
screen -S MySessionName -p 0 -X stuff "myprogram"$'\n'
```

then saved this as a `.sh` file, and ran `chmod a+x` on it. In Finder, I used `Cmd-I` to set Terminal.app as the default way to open `.sh` type files. Then simply go to System Preferences->Users and Accounts->Login Items, click `+` and add the file.

References:

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/983176/667707
2. https://superuser.com/a/307486/691289
3. https://superuser.com/a/995564/691289