# How can I make this SED command more portable?

Tags: sed, compatibility, gnu, bsd

I'm using the following `sed` command:

```
cat version | sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9:M]*-[abp]/Ver\n/'
```

Which normalizes like this:

```
4330M-p  ->  Ver<newline>
```

This works fine with GNU SED, but with BSD SED on Mac OS X, the \n turns into an `n` like this:

```
4330M-p  ->  Vern
```

To normalize some output that contains a version number that changes over time to a static string, followed by a newline.  This is used as part of testing where the output after `sed` processing is compared via `diff` with a known golden file and we don't want failures due to the version number changing and further need a newline added for our purposes.

How can I replace with a string that adds a newline in a way that works on both GNU and BSD version of `sed`, or should I just install GNU `sed` on Mac OS X because this cannot be done?

Comment: I haven't tried BSD sed, but perhaps something like `\d13` or something like `\x0a`?  that works in GNU does it work in BSD?

Comment: @barlop, Nope, the backslash is eaten by BSD `sed` and you get `Verd13` and `verx0a`.

Comment: this may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421478/how-do-i-use-a-new-line-replacement-in-a-bsd-sed  and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42321/how-can-i-instruct-bsd-sed-to-interpret-escape-sequences-like-n-and-t and http://superuser.com/questions/307165/newlines-in-sed-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

You can make a literal newline in your script, like so:

```
cat version | sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9:M]*-[abp]/Ver\
/'
```

Comment: This works, but is ugly.

Comment: @WilliamKF you could also install GNU sed, but that is not a great solution either. If you have a prettier solution, then by all means use it.